# Using AVCaptureEventInteraction for Volume Button Shutter Capture

Tags: ios, swift, volume, avkit

I've been officially notified that iOS 17.2 contains the new API to officially support volume button actuation for photo capture in a camera app.

API is called `AVCaptureEventInteraction`
[Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avcaptureeventinteraction)

So If I use the [AVCam sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avcam_building_a_camera_app), How would I be able to attach this interaction?

```
    if #available(iOS 17.2, *) {
       let interaction = AVCaptureEventInteraction { event in
             print ("AVCaptureEventInteraction Fired")
       }
    }
```

API does not contain any details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to integrate [`AVCaptureEventInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avcaptureeventinteraction) into the [`AVCaptureSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/) or a related component.
The API usage could look like this:

```swift
if #available(iOS 17.2, *) {
    let interaction = AVCaptureEventInteraction { event in
        // Handle the volume button press event here
        // e.g., Trigger photo capture
        print("AVCaptureEventInteraction Fired")
    }
    // Add the interaction to your capture session or related component
    // That might depend on further details from the API documentation
    captureSession.addInteraction(interaction)
}
```

But, since the `AVCaptureEventInteraction` API documentation is not detailed, you might need to experiment with where to add this interaction within the `AVCaptureSession` setup. A likely place is right after initializing the session and before starting it.
I tried a [quick search on GitHub](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+%22AVCaptureSession%22+%22AVCaptureEventInteraction%22)... and found nothing(!)

You could try and add the `AVCaptureEventInteraction` initialization in the `configureSession` method of the `AVCam` sample, after setting up the session but before starting it.
Inside the closure of `AVCaptureEventInteraction`, implement the logic to capture a photo when the volume button is pressed. Add the interaction to the `AVCaptureSession`.

```swift
func configureSession() {
    // existing setup code for AVCaptureSession 

    if #available(iOS 17.2, *) {
        let interaction = AVCaptureEventInteraction { event in
            // Implement the logic to capture a photo
            print("AVCaptureEventInteraction Fired")
            // Example: self.capturePhoto()
        }
        captureSession.addInteraction(interaction)
    }

    // rest of the session configuration 
}
```

Replace `self.capturePhoto()` with the actual method used in AVCam to capture a photo.

Answer (score 2):

`AVCaptureEventInteraction` implements the `UIInterAction` protocol. So you should attach the `AVCaptureEventInteraction` to a UI element (*e.g.* your shutter button) that is part of the responder chain.

Example:

```
if #available(iOS 17.2, *) {
    let shutterEventInteraction = AVCaptureEventInteraction.init { event in
        print(event)
        if (event.phase == AVCaptureEventPhase.began) {
            self.performCapture()
        }
    }
    shutterEventInteraction.isEnabled = true
    self.shutterButton.addInteraction(shutterEventInteraction)
}
```

Comment: Good point. Upvoted.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Something I noticed — If you use other initializer for primary and secondary, primary is always volume down, but secondary is volume up AND Action Button. having this interaction enabled disables Action Button shortcuts. I wonder if there is a way around this...